# Run AlexNet: cuda_error_out_of_memory error

Tags: tensorflow

Gpu memory:11.9G

Init alexnet: need 34G, so out of memory.

use the one of the two ways of tensorflow official web as below, but still the old question.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.7
session = tf.Session(config=config) 

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config)
```

why?? any good ideas, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The real reason is that in shuffle the min_after_dequeue is too big